# How to find text start and end with ^ and replace it using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an HTML. The contents of the HTML are something like below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .....
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        ....
        <p class=TableaParagraph>
            <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Calibri">
                ^BUYER-NAME-FIRST^Buyer Last Name:
            </span>
        </p>
        <p class=TableaParagraph>
            <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Calibri">
                ^COBUYER-NAME-LAST COBUYER-NUMBER="1"^Current Address:
            </span>
        </p>
        ....
        <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 9pt; font-family: Calibri">
            Total Earnest Deposits paid upon signing this agreement^TOTAL-EARNEST-DEPOSIT-AMOUNT^
        </span>
        .....
    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML hane some custom tags that start with `^` and also end with `^`, like `^COBUYER-NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER="1"^` These tags can appear any where in the html. I want to find each tag that starts and end with `^` and replace it with the value.

The problem is in jquery selector `^` is use for `start` and `$` is use for `end`. But here my tag also contain `^`. So how can I find the tags and replace it with the value. Like in place of `^BUYER-NAME-FIRST^`, I want to replace it with `Basit`.

Once I will get all the tags, then I'wll have to loop over it to replace the value. But how can I get all the tags in this HTML in efficient way.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
String html = rtfService.convertRTFToHtml(rtfFile);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements links = doc.select("span[href]");
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the jsoup docs? What issues are you running into?

Comment: issue to find a selector expression that select all the custom tags ?

Comment: You could try using regular expressions to pick out the bits you want. You cannot _parse_ HTML using regular expressions, but you should be able to pick out everything between `[^][A-Z0-9-="]+[^]`.

Comment: Elements represent a collection od html elements. Your tags are not html elements - they are just a text. 
You can preprocess html content with regex - `\^.*?\^` will find all your tags, then you can replace them tith some values.

Comment: *"These tags can appear any where in the html"* Inside attribute values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there aren't tags, they're just text within elements.

jSoup supports the `:contains` pseudo-selector and, more usefully in your case, the `:containsOwn` pseudo-selector; [details](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html). So you can find elements that contain `^`:

```java
Elements matches = doc.select("*:containsOwn(^)");
```

...and then loop through those using a regular expression (probably) or similar on the element's text nodes to find the matching `^...^` tokens and replace them with the appropriate values.

Comment: You are absolutely right. My tags are just text within the elements.